You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode. I can't print a code .py with special characters
I have this two simple lines of python code (test.py):
#################################################
# col.set_

and this is my latex code:
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\lstdefinestyle{chstyle}{%
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!12},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    commentstyle=\color{green!60!black},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    stringstyle=\color{blue!50!red},
    showstringspaces=false,
    %captionpos=b,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\footnotesize\color{gray},
    numbersep=10pt,
    %stepnumber=2,
    tabsize=2,
    frame=L,
    framerule=1pt,
    rulecolor=\color{red},
    breaklines=true,
    inputpath=
}
\begin{document}
    
\lstset{inputencoding=utf8/latin1}  
\lstset{language=Python,texcl=true}
\lstinputlisting[language=Python, style=chstyle, firstline=1, lastline=50, caption=Solución Miniproyecto 1, label=py-sample]{test.py}

\end{document}

I can't build and view correctly, I don't understand these errors:
You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode. ...##########
Missing $ inserted. ... Miniproyecto 1, label=py-sample]{test.py}
Extra }, or forgotten $. ... Miniproyecto 1, label=py-sample]{test.py}

I really appreciated any help
Eric


Remove \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}, it doesn't do anything useful nowadays.

@Skillmon it errors for me. I had to remove texcl=true to get it working.

@Skillmon it errors for me on texlive.net too (I generated the test.py file with filecontents [noheader]).

I removed texcl=true and worked for me, thank you very match for all answers

From the manual of listings:

When the language is Python, # is the comment character and therefore everything that follows the first one (on the same line) is treated as LaTeX code. The second # triggers the error.
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.py}
#################################################
# col.set_
á è ñ
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname2.py}
# \normalfont This is a \LaTeX\ comment
# \normalfont col.set\_
á è ñ
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}%%%%% NO!!!
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\lstdefinestyle{chstyle}{%
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!12},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    commentstyle=\color{green!60!black},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    stringstyle=\color{blue!50!red},
    showstringspaces=false,
    %captionpos=b,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\footnotesize\color{gray},
    numbersep=10pt,
    %stepnumber=2,
    tabsize=2,
    frame=L,
    framerule=1pt,
    rulecolor=\color{red},
    breaklines=true,
    inputpath=
}
\begin{document}
    
\lstset{inputencoding=utf8/latin1}
\lstinputlisting[
  language=Python,
  style=chstyle,
  firstline=1,
  lastline=50,
  caption=Solución Miniproyecto 1,
  label=py-sample,
]{\jobname.py}

\lstinputlisting[
  language=Python,
  style=chstyle,
  firstline=1,
  lastline=50,
  caption=Solución Miniproyecto 2,
  label=py-sample2,
  texcl=true,
]{\jobname2.py}

\end{document}

I used filecontents just to make the example self-contained; any external file can be used.

